# Where can I find a list of Facebook's networks?

Tags: facebook

Facebook used to list all their networks here: http://www.facebook.com/networks/networks.php, but they removed it sometime last week. Does anyone know where I can find a list of Facebook's networks?

Comment: whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'

From -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164672/list-of-ip-space-used-by-facebook

Comment: whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS32934'

From -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164672/list-of-ip-space-used-by-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they got rid of it when they [discontinued their `Network Pages`](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13515_3-9941089-26.html). Although Google returns http://www.facebook.com/networks.php as the first result for `facebook networks` neither does this link have something nor does Google have a cached copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is for particular place and protected group network.
You will not find any networks if you search like this...

Only it will be available if you have email id of a particular community or network